# SqlConnection behaves differently in web project and in NserviceBus hosted service

Tags: c#, sql-server, nservicebus

I have the following piece of code running in a web project and in a class library, hosted on NserviceBus host.

```
public static TravellerChannelModel GetTravellerInfo(Guid travellerId)
{
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_travellerConnectionString))
        {
            var repo = new TravellerChannelRepository(_log, conn);
            var travellerModel = repo.FindAll(travellerId).FirstOrDefault();

            return travellerModel;
        }
    }
```

In the web project it works fine. In class library I get an exception

> ServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver Failed to process message
>   System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and 
>   available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean 
>   async)...

If I add

```
conn.Open();
```

right after "using", it works. Anybody knows the reason?

**UPDATE:**

Here is TravellerChannelRepository. SqlDataAdapter was not used.

I know that I have to open connection before querying and modifying data. In this case I'm curious what opens the connection instead of me doing it explicitly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;
using DapperExtensions;
using log4net;

namespace Traveller
{
    public class TravellerChannelRepository
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;
        private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

        public TravellerChannelRepository(ILog log, IDbConnection connection)
        {
            _log = log;
            _connection = connection;
        }        

        public IEnumerable<TravellerChannelModel> FindAll(Guid travellerId)
        {
            IFieldPredicate predicate = Predicates.Field<TravellerChannelModel>(x => x.TravellerId, Operator.Eq, travellerId);

            return _connection.GetList<TravellerChannelModel>(predicate);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You *always* need to *open* a connection before using it - I'm surprised it would work in your web app..... just get in the habit of *opening* a connection before using it, and closing it right away after you're done

Comment: Yeah. I go into that - I doubt your claim it works in a web proejct because unless TravellerChannelRepository opens the connection, it is simply broken code, regardless where. Connections MUST be opened before use.

Answer (score 0):

A SqlConnection always has to be opened before querying or updating data. The only thing from the top of my head, that does not need this, is the SqlDataAdapter as this will automatically open the connection for you.

Some code in your samples is hidden behind the following line:

```
var repo = new TravellerChannelRepository(_log, conn);
```

Perhaps you're opening the connection there?

Anyway, it's 100% perfectly fine to open the connection before using it.

Comment: But the code in the web project, what does it look like? Because there the connection is automatically opened, right? If you want to know why, I'd love to compare both projects.